# How to add panel to icon from toolbarbutton library

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I tried to use Erik Vold's toolbarbutton library to add a button near the addressbar. But it doesn't have panel option like widgets have. I just want the same as widgets with onclick panel do but the icon should be near the addressbar or smth like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a panel option in the toolbarbutton module, iirc it works the same as the widget module.

https://github.com/voldsoftware/toolbarbutton-jplib/blob/master/docs/toolbarbutton.md

Comment: Thanks tested it - it works :) One q, how to change button icon? `tb.image = data.url('new_icon.png')` seems not work, I use 'destroy()' instead.